# как узнать какой чекбокс выбран чтобы через js или jquery изменить его value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="row input_block">
                        
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input name="print" type="checkbox" value="{{$parameter->print}}" {{$parameter->print == '1' ? 'checked' : ''}} class="field check" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                        
                </div>
<div class="row input_block">
                        
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input name="print" type="checkbox" value="{{$parameter->print}}" {{$parameter->print == '1' ? 'checked' : ''}} class="field check" style="width: 100%;">
                        </div>
                        
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

уже решил

```js
$('.check').change(function() {
                $(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0);
                            alert($(this).val());
            });
```

Comment: Если именно 1 или 0, можно вспомнить, что если превратить true в число, он станет 1, а false → 0) Оттуда `$('.check').change(function() { $(this).val(+$(this).prop('checked')); });` — плюсик превращает значение в число.